# Using rxjs in angular 2 component, should I manually import the operators?

Tags: angular, rxjs

The documentation for http has [this example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html):

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: 'people.html'
})

class PeopleComponent {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('people.son')]
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
  }
}
```

However, I need to add this line: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map` to make it work.

Do I have my configuration different or the import is missing in the example?

Comment: Yes you have to add Rxjs first

Comment: I'd suggest to just `import 'rxjs/Rx'` in bootstrap, makes things easier in development. Than remove it for production if you need and replace it with individual operator imports (or make build tools do it...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Server Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) dev guide discusses/mentions/explains this:

> The RxJS library is quite large. Size matters when we build a production application and deploy it to mobile devices. We should include only those features that we actually need.
>
> Accordingly, Angular exposes a stripped down version of `Observable` in the `rxjs/Observable` module, a version that lacks almost all operators including the ones we'd like to use here such as the `map` method...
>
> It's up to us to add the operators we need. We could add each operator, one-by-one, until we had a custom Observable implementation tuned precisely to our requirements.

E.g., as you stated, add map explicitly:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Or, if we're lazy we can just pull in the full set of operators:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```